# Supervisor discourages me from using a method he doesn't know. Can I work on it and publish it by myself?

Tags: phd, computer-science, research-topic

Either my supervisor is wrong in not letting me work on an idea which he does not understand, my bad that I am  stuck with someone who is not open-minded. But I suck it up.

But I am enthusiastic about the idea and wish to work on it myself. I can find time for it and it is very useful for my future opportunities. My supervisor is not really worried about my future.

So firstly, how to manage this exercise by getting what I want, having no effect on my PhD and keeping my supervisor not too angry (after all my Phd is still influenced by this guy). Secondly, is it ok to write it up myself and publish it? I am not using any ideas from my supervisor for this work, of course the learning from previous works will be used - which is already published!

Comment: How is this question different from your previous questions, [I wish to try out a technique which my supervisor does not want me to, because its not his expertise](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/80153/i-wish-to-try-out-a-technique-which-my-supervisor-does-not-want-me-to-because-i) and [I want to change my thesis topic (to the extent that the ethos is still in tact) but my advisor does not agree. What can I do?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/73284/i-want-to-change-my-thesis-topic-to-the-extent-that-the-ethos-is-still-in-tact)

Comment: It's pretty clear from your other posts that you've already made up your mind about who is right, despite anything people here say. Not sure why you keep asking.

Comment: @ff524 If you find this question a duplicate, just say that and be quite. If I have made my mind or not, is none of your business. Your rudeness is not appreciated and I suggest you stop moderating if that is your nature.